# Android SM-A01F5 Stuck on boot loader

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, custom-roms

after attempting to flash the device using Odin3 I've got an issue.

got a Samsung SM-A01F5 Device which has the following issues:

- Can't enter Download Mode
- Can't use FastBoot to flash the device
- Factory Reset (with wipe) doesn't change anything
- Can't open SD Card directory

What it can do:

- boot into the bootloader menu (the only options are)

  - start, restart, recovery mode, power off
- boot into the  "Android Recovery" menu, with the following options (in brackets are my thoughts)

  - Reboot system now
  - Reboot to bootloader
  - Apply update from ADB (works but it limited)
  - Apply update from SD card (doesn't work)
  - Wipe data/factory reset
  - Wipe cache partition
  - Mount /system (doesn't work)
  - when doing this i get an error of ""Fail to find block device for partition)
  - view recovery logs
  - run graphics test
  - run locale test
  - power off

I've tried flashing these ROMs with Odin3

- A015FXXU4AUB2_A015FOJM4AUB2_XSG
- SM-A015F_1_20200302114054_jsgb2nfkoc_fac
- SM-A015F_A015FXXU4BUD8_A015FOLM4BUD8_HiepGia_SSV

all 3 of these roms would get stuck on prisim.img

TIA.

### Edit 1:

I have gotten the download mode on now, thanks.